# Get application environment constant in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

i am new to Zend Framework and i want to know how to get the application environment in my controller.

I read in a forum to use: `echo getenv('APPLICATION_ENV');`  but it does not work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since `APPLICATION_ENV` is a constant, you can access it simply with:

```
echo APPLICATION_ENV;
```

But the question is why would you need it in your controller.

Comment: I agree with Vika. There is no need to know in which environment you are in your controller (or in any other part of your application). If you start doing different things in your application depending of the environment, you're doing it (very) wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the tip... i was just curious to fetch the value of that constant in my controller. I am not doing anything specific to it.

Comment: What about handling errors gracefully and differently in different environments?

Comment: I would also ask, what if you want to add an action or two that should only be available in a testing or development environment. Is there a more elegant way to handle such a thing?

Comment: Or to not send emails when testing / stage / development.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to get the environment name. It's a little more OO-friendly for those of us who prefer to avoid globally defined constants, but I'm not quite sure how to get at it:

```
$myEnvName = $zendApplicationInstance->getEnvironment();
```

The question here is how to get the reference to `$myEnvName` -- suggestions welcome.